# How to prevent inserting "" or [] (empty string) as value in JSON column in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to prevent insertion of "" or [] (empty strings/array) in json column. Please consider the following example :-

```
{"city":"LONDON","country":"UK","addressLine1":"PO Box 223456","postCode":"","addressLine2":"PO Box 47854"}
```

then the output should remove "postcode":"" and should appear as below :-

```
{"city":"LONDON","country":"UK","addressLine1":"PO Box 223456","addressLine2":"PO Box 47854"}
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Why don't you check for this in your application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove these empty values in the way like this:

```
with my_table(json_col) as (
values (
'{
    "city": "LONDON",
    "country": "UK",
    "addressLine1": "PO Box 223456",
    "postCode": "",
    "addressLine2": "PO Box 47854",
    "array_to_delete": []
}'::jsonb)
)

select jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
from my_table
cross join lateral jsonb_each(json_col)
where value not in ('""', '[]');

                                           jsonb_object_agg                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"city": "LONDON", "country": "UK", "addressLine1": "PO Box 223456", "addressLine2": "PO Box 47854"}
(1 row)
```

---

Update. In Postgres 9.3:

```
with my_table(json_col) as (
values (
'{
    "city": "LONDON",
    "country": "UK",
    "addressLine1": "PO Box 223456",
    "postCode": "",
    "addressLine2": "PO Box 47854",
    "array_to_delete": []
}'::json)
)

select format('{%s}',string_agg(format('"%s": %s', key, to_json(value)), ','))::json
from my_table
cross join lateral json_each_text(json_col)
where value not in ('', '[]');

                                              format                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"city": "LONDON","country": "UK","addressLine1": "PO Box 223456","addressLine2": "PO Box 47854"}
(1 row)
```

---

Update. In this case a check constraint cannot be applied, because it can only accept or reject input data, while you want to modify it. You can create a function with the above algorithm and use it in a trigger:

```
create or replace function filter_json_input()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    select format('{%s}', string_agg(format('"%s": %s', key, to_json(value)), ','))::json
    from json_each_text(new.json_col)
    where value not in ('', '[]')
    into new.json_col;
    return new;
end $$;
```

[Full example in rextester.](http://rextester.com/QOX9326)

Comment: Thanks but I am running postgres v 9.3 and this function is not supported over there.

Comment: The server version should be included in the question, especially if it is not the current one. See the updated answer.

Comment: Better to call TO_JSON on `value` when recreating the json object, otherwise you'll put integers etc in quotes.

Comment: @eurotrash - unfortunately, `to_json()` changes nothing, as the argument is always `text.` On the other hand, you cannot use `json_each()` as the type `json` has no equality operator. So better is to keep the query as simple as possible.

Comment: Right you are, I forgot all the input is text :( However still worth calling it, because simply putting quotes around text doesn't handle cases where, for example, the value contains quotes. Try adding this to your json input: `"test":"something \"in\" quotes"` and the query fails.

Comment: Yes, this type of conversions is often sensitive to corner cases, what makes them clumsy. This only proves that the best option is to upgrade to Postgres 10 and always keep the software up-to-date. (I've updated the answer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @klin
However, this needs to be altered and inserted at the same time when front end application tries to insert the data in a table. I was wondering if this can be achieved through check constraint.

Comment: Thanks @klin. I guess we are almost there.
I tried but the "postCode": "" doesn't get removed. Is there any way in which we can remove the postcode : "" as well.

Comment: Try it now, there was a typo in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) you can do it with the following query:

```
WITH j AS(
SELECT *
FROM json_each_text('{"city":"LONDON","country":"UK","addressLine1":"PO Box 223456","postCode":"","addressLine2":"PO Box 47854"}'::json)
WHERE value <> ''
) SELECT json_object_agg(j.key,j.value) FROM j
```

Comment: Thanks but I am running postgres v 9.3 and this function is not supported over there.

Answer (score 0):

I use PG 9.3 as well. Here's a solution... maybe too hacky? But it works, and we frequently build JSON objects manually as it's faster :P

```
SELECT ('{' || STRING_AGG('"' || key || '":' || TO_JSON(value), ',') || '}')::JSON
FROM json_each_text('{"city":"LONDON","country":"UK","addressLine1":"PO Box 223456","postCode":"","addressLine2":"PO Box 47854"}'::JSON)
WHERE COALESCE(value, '') <> ''
```

Result: `{"city":"LONDON","country":"UK","addressLine1":"PO Box 223456","addressLine2":"PO Box 47854"}`

Comment: Can this be implemented at run time, that means when the application tries to insert the json data in column then it should check whether it has "" or [] and if it finds, then ""/[] should get removed and then get inserted.